# Implementing BChain in rblpapi?

Tags: r, excel, bloomberg, rblpapi

Is there any way of implementing the Excel Bloomberg formula BChain in R via the Rblpapi library?

Sample formula for Excel:

```
=BChain("AAPL US Equity","BONDS","CONVERTIBLE == False","UseActiveOnly","True")
```

Comment: This didn't work in the Bloomberg excel API for me when I tried.  Are you sure the above works?

Comment: Corrected formula - this definitely works. Thanks!